# Is the theory of the rational ordered field countably categorical?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{Q},+,-,\times,0,1,<).$ Now certainly, by Lowenheim-Skolem, we can't have a set of sentences in first-order logic whose models are precisely that structure and any structure isomorphic to it. But what if we require the model to be countable? That is, if a countably infinite ordered field satisfies the theory of the rational ordered field, is it isomorphic to the rational ordered field?

Edit: Also, if the answer is no, can someone exhibit an ordered field not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ which satisfies its complete theory?

Comment: I’m not sure why $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ is not a model.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3830598/7062

Comment: Nice. @AlexKruckman

Comment: The answers given below answer the question quite completely, I think, but just as an aside: the integers are definable in the (pure) field of rationals (this is a nontrivial theorem due to Julia Robinson). It follows that so are the natural numbers (which are the sums of squares of four integers). Thus, it is interdefinable with the arithmetic, and as such, is about as wild as it gets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By compactness, $\mathbb{Q}$ has a non-Archimedean elementary extension $\mathcal{A}$. Of course $\mathcal{A}$ may be uncountable, but we can get around that: let $a\in\mathcal{A}$ be an infinite element, and apply downward Lowenheim-Skolem to get a countable $\mathcal{B}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{A}$ with $a\in \mathcal{B}$.

Since $\mathcal{B}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{A}\equiv\mathbb{Q}$ we have $\mathcal{B}\equiv\mathbb{Q}$. But by choice of $a$, $\mathcal{B}$ must be non-Archimedean - and so not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

**EDIT: Whoops, I was *really* wrong initially - here's a correct statement:**

It turns out in fact that there's a very useful general principle available to us: if $T$ is a (complete, countable language) theory which interprets a non-$\aleph_0$-categorical theory, then $T$ itself is not $\aleph_0$-categorical. So we can prove non-categoricity just by finding "bad configurations." This is a consequence of the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem, that a (countable complete) first-order theory is $\aleph_0$-categorical iff it has finitely many $n$-types for each $n$. See [Alex Kruckman's comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123634/is-the-theory-of-the-rational-ordered-field-countably-categorical/4123642?noredirect=1#comment8529332_4123642).

Comment: That makes more sense, but what does $\mathcal{A}\equiv\Bbb Q$ indicate? Since $\mathcal{A}$ may be uncountable, it doesn't indicate equipotence, and since $\mathcal{A}$ is non-Archimedean, it doesn't indicate isomorphism.

Comment: @CameronBuie It's the standard notation for [elementary equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence).

Comment: +1: Gotcha. Nice approach! I don't quite get the counterexample, yet, but it intrigues me! :-)

Comment: Hi Noah - I don't think your counterexample does what you want. $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal{X})$ isn't countably categorical because the "distance $n$" relations are definable for all $n$, contradicting Ryll-Nardzewski. The extra models will come from the fact that you can't control how many "new" $\mathbb{Z}$-chains are related to each rational  $q$ (but not to any $p<q$).

Comment: On the other hand, it *is* possible to prove that if $T$ is a countably categorical theory in a countable language and $T'$ is a complete theory interpretable in $T$, then $T'$ is countably categorical. It's an immediate consequence of Ryll-Nardzewski: If $T'$ has infinitely many inequivalent formulas in $n$ free variables for some $n$, then $T$ does too.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Argh, you're quite right! Fixing ...

Comment: @CameronBuie I was wrong, see Alex's comment (and my imminent edit).

Comment: Anyway, what did the counterexample have to do with the original question?

Comment: @AlexKruckman The OP had earlier asked a question whose answer involved the definability of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. With this in mind, the counterexample *would have* indicated that that definability result + non-$\aleph_0$-categoricity of $\mathbb{Z}$ (which I think the OP already asked about even earlier?) would not be enough to settle the $\mathbb{Q}$-case. But I was wrong anyways, so ...

Answer (score 4):

Your question admits a very strong negative answer: No infinite integral domain has a countably categorical theory.

Further, you can take "infinite integral domain" to mean any infinite structure $R$ in a countable language $L$ containing the language of rings, such that the reduct of $R$ to the language of rings is an integral domain. So, for example, this applies to the ordered field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $R$ be an infinite integral domain. For every $n$, the polynomial $x^n - 1$ has at most $n$ roots in $R$, so since $R$ is infinite, there is no finite upper bound on the  multiplicative orders of non-zero elements of $R$. Then the formulas $y = x^n$ are pairwise inequivalent for all $n$ (given $m < n$, if $a\in R$ is a non-zero element of multiplicative order greater than $n$, and $b = a^n$, then $R\models b = a^n$, but $R\not\models b = a^m$). By the [Ryll-Nardzewski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-categorical_theory#Equivalent_conditions_for_omega-categoricity), $\text{Th}(R)$ is not countably categorical.