# Field elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, model-theory

I am interested in the theory of rational numbers in the language of rings $\{+,\cdot,0,1\}$.

Of course, this theory is extremely complicated, but I hope to find some non-standard models.

One obvious construction are ultrapowers of $\mathbb{Q}$.

It seems to me that other examples are very hard to get. Some easy necessary properties are characteristic 0, admitting a unique total order, every element not in the prime field being transcendental over it etc.

I would be very thankful for any ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$?

Comment: This field is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(X)$ which can be ordered in many different ways. For instance by plugging in any real number for $X$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3830556/7062

Comment: The many orderings of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ are not quite enough on their own to show this field is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$, since unique orderability is not a first-order property. You need the stronger fact that every positive element is a sum of just four squares in $\mathbb{Q}$ to see that every elementarily equivalent field is uniquely orderable.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, those are good observations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "finding" a nonstandard model.

The structures $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are bi-interpretable. In one direction, $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in $\mathbb{Q}$ by a famous theorem of Julia Robinson. In the other direction, the usual constructions of $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ are first-order interpretations.

So a field elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ is essentially the same thing as a model of true arithmetic, the complete theory of $\mathbb{N}$.

There is an extensive literature on nonstandard models of arithmetic (see Kaye's book, for example), but these objects are notoriously complicated. For example, by [Tennenbaum's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem), no such model is computable. This suggests that we're not going to find any very explicit nonstandard model of the complete theory of $\mathbb{Q}$. Someone else might be able to say something more precise along these lines.

Nontrivial ultraproducts are not very explicit, of course, since they require fixing a non-principal ultrafilter. But if you view ultrproducts as a satisfying construction, I'll point out that model theory gives many other tools for building models of general first-order theories: the compactness theorem, realizing and omitting types, Löwenheim-Skolem, saturated models, Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models, etc. etc.

Comment: As far as explicit ultrapowers, if you structure actually lives in $L$, you can just consider the ultrapower as computed in $L$, by the least free ultrafilter in $L$ (according to the $<_L$ well-ordering). Even if the resulting structure is countable in your universe, it is still fairly explicit, and non-standard. Having said that, this is by no means an "explicit description" of any kind, shape, or form.